# Rails - many to many queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm building a small project to learn rails and am having a really, really hard time querying data with a many to many relationship.

The 4 models in question are user, test, take, and provide. Users can take many tests and tests can be taken by many users. Users can also provide many tests, and tests can by provided by many users.

Here are my models:

```
class Provide < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :test
end

class Take < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :test
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tests, through: :take
    has_many :tests, through: :provide
    has_one :user_type
end

class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, through: :take
    has_many :users, through: :provide
    has_many :questions
end
```

Now, what I want to get is these 2 queries:

```
-- information on users providing a specific test
select u.*
from   users u
       join provides p
           on u.id = p.user_id
       join tests t
           on t.id = p.test_id
where t.id = '1'

-- get information for all users currently taking a test
select u.*
from   users u
       join takes tak
           on u.id = tak.user_id
       join tests tes
           on tes.id = tak.test_id
where tes.id = '1'
```

So, from what I gather, I should be able to query similarly to a one to many relationship and just use :includes, but I just can't seem to get this to work.

Here's what I mean:

```
@Test = Test.includes(:users).where("id = ?", 1)
```

From here, I was expecting to access users with something like:

```
@Test.users.all
```

Anybody have any input? This is driving me nuts, and I can't find a good example of this on the rails docs... I can't believe it's not a common problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forgot to add the associations to `takes` and `provides` for both `user` and `test`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :takes
  has_many :tests, through: :takes

  has_many :provides
  has_many :tests, through: :provides
end

class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :takes
  has_many :users, through: :takes

  has_many :provides
  has_many :users, through: :provides
end
```

Comment: Ok, I've added those associations, but it doesn't seem to change anything with my query. Do I have it formatted correctly?

Comment: take note of the plural `takes` and `provides` passed to the `through` option.  it that still doesn't work, it would help if you can tell us the error you're getting, if any.

Comment: Hey, you're right, that did the trick! I was trying to test via the rails console, but that wasn't working. It worked fine when I tested through the rails app itself.

Comment: in the rails console, classes are cached.  After running the console and you made some changes to a model, you need to call `reload!`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about console. Helped me out as well.